# What do we mean by 'closed' in this context

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Given Lie Group $G\equiv GL(n,\mathbb{K})$, I am trying to understand what is meant by a closed subgroup of $H< G$ with respect to the induced topology. Need clarification on the following points:

1. By induced topology, what do we mean?
2. Definition of closed subgroup in this context?

To give an example, consider a map $\phi: GL(n,\mathbb{K})\to Sym(n,\mathbb{K})$ such that $\phi(X)=XX^T$. How do we determine if $Sym(n,\mathbb{K})$ is closed or not?

Comment: My guess: 1.$G$ is subset of $\mathbb{K}^{n^2}$, hence induce a topology. 2. $H$ is closed in $G$

Comment: 1. It means the subspace topology with respect to the embedding of $GL_n(K)$ into $K^{n \times n}$, where the latter has the Euclidean topology. 2. A closed subgroup is a subgroup that's closed in the usual topological sense. 3. This isn't a subgroup, and it's not clear whether you're referring to the image of your map or to all symmetric matrices. Which is it?